# FLUTTER-WEB file.writeAsBytes not working

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I have been trying to generate pdfs using pdf plugin and wrtie it to a pdf file using file.writeAsBytes but it's not creating any files and its not even throwing any errors or giving any response.I'm using pdf plugin and trying to follow its example.

link https://pub.dev/packages/path#-example-tab-

```
void makePdf() async {

  final pw.Document doc = pw.Document();
  pw.Font font = pw.Font.ttf(await rootBundle.load('assets/Exo-Bold.ttf'));

doc.addPage(
  pw.Page(
    pageFormat: pdf.PdfPageFormat.a4,
    build: (pw.Context context) {
      return pw.Center(
        child: pw.Text(
          "Hello World",
          style: pw.TextStyle(font: font),
        ),
      ); // Center
    },
  ),
);

final file = File("ms.pdf");

List<int> data = doc.save();
// print(data);

file.writeAsBytes(data).then((file) {
  print("done");
}).catchError((e) => print(e));
```

}

Comment: `writeAsBytes` after upgrade to flutter 3

Answer (score 0):

I think you need specify the path

```
String directory = (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path;
final pdfName = '$directory/recipet.pdf';
final File file = File(pdfName);
await file.writeAsBytes(doc.save());
```